# How are you meant to do this so that it works? SVN tree conflicts, etc

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have a trunk that we've branched.
In the branch we moved files using TortoiseSVN into new folders to re-organise the structure.
Those files were also worked on in the trunk.
So let's call the file /trunk/file1.cs
and /branch/folder1/file1.cs

We're now trying to merge the trunk changes into the branch and svn is screaming about tree conflicts?

How are you meant to do this scenario.

btw we're using svn 1.6.6 on both server and client although upgrade was done after the branch was created (not sure if that makes a difference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the file to where it is supposed to be (Subversion complains because it can't figure this out by itself), and then mark the conflict as resolved.

Comment: Once it is checked in, you can use SVN commands to move the files around.

Comment: The situation though is that changes have been done to the version in the trunk and the version in the branch.
So how do I merge the code changes from the trunk into the branch? 
SVN just says tree conflict. If I resolve the tree conflict I lose the change to the file that were done in trunk :(